# Removing overflow-x:hidden; when page is minimized

Tags: html, css

I have tried wording this question in many different ways on Google. I have found one result with a similar question. The response was that the question was too vague. This will be my first question, I'll do my best to try and be as detailed as possible.
The very page that this question is being asked on has no scroll bar at the bottom, suggesting    `overflow-x:hidden`    was used. However when clicking on the restore down icon at the top right of the page, left of the close icon, you will notice that the x or left to right scroll bar is now present. This is the effect that I am trying to achieve. How do I write my page where it has no left to right scroll bar until minimized? 
Here is the code that I have in CSS:

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden; 
overflow-y:auto; 
width:1650px;
max-width:1650px; background-image:url('LiraBG5.png'), url('LiraBG3.png');  
background-repeat:repeat-x, repeat; height:100%;
}
```

For HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>    
<link href="Lira.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>    
<body id="body">    
</body>    
</html>
```

I have tried    `overflow-x:auto;`     in place of    `overflow-x:hidden;`    however this results in the page having an x or left to right scroll bar when maximized which is what I am trying to avoid. Is it possible that it may require JavaScript for this effect?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. People may be able to help you better if you posted the relevant code from your project or if you were to duplicate your issue using JS.Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) Reading through your question now is very confusing and the code posted is not very helpful.

Comment: A width of 1650px is too much for a website. Please read and understand the usability of websites. You can set `width` to 100% and set a minimum witdh like this: `min-width`.

Comment: @crazymatt Stop using jsFiddle on SO, you can use an integrated **code snippet** which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @forever just suggest that to the OP. I personally prefer to use fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `overflow-x: hidden` - that won't give you a scrollbar. Remove that from the body and try something like this (run the snippet and click "full page" to see it in action)

```css
#content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Content here</div>
```

This tells the `div` to fix its size at 1000 pixels wide, and `margin: 0 auto` tells it to centre itself horizontally if there's room. If there isn't room, you'll get a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML element of the document, by default, has `overflow: auto`. This causes scrollbars to appear when the content within the document extends beyond the boundries of the browser window.

In the case of this website. There is a centered div which has a width of `1000px`. When the browser window width is reduced below `1000px` then the overflow on the html element will display by default.

As a side note:
Many modern websites are built with a responsive framework (eg. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)). These responsive frameworks ensure that all content is visible within the viewport regardless of the window size and therefore remove the need for horizontal scrolling.